# Contents of OCSP packets?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

As far as I know, the web browser use OCSP packets to check if the incoming certificate (from a web server) is still valid or it is revoked.

I have some questions about it:

1- Am I Right about the OCSP?

2- Does the browser send a OCSP request for every incoming cert?

3- Where is the destication of these requests? Root CA?

Well, I monitor the data transmission on my network adapter using Wireshark and I catch the following request :

*click to enlarge*

[[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5PzL.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5PzL.jpg)

Well, above observation added 3 more question to above questions:

4- I did a whois IP the destination IP and the result shows that it is [a23-51-123-27.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com](http://a23-51-123-27.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com) . Is it really a Root CA?

5- This request is sent in plain and is not encrypted with SSL protocol! Why? Can't it simply attacked with MITM attacks?

6- This packet contains *issuerNameHash*, *issuerKeyHash* and *serialNumber* only! Are they enough really?! Why hashed values sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a lot of questions to answer.

1. Web browser will check OCSP responder for certificate revocation information only if it is set (to do so) in the browser settings and only if there is URL to OCSP in the certificate to validate.
2. First a certificate chain is built. Each certificate in the chain (excluding root which is trusted in your certificate store, or not :) ) will be validated by OCSP (if conditions in "1" are met).
3. It's not RootCA for every certificate. Each certificate in chain could contain url to OCSP server. OCSP server certificate has to be issued by the CA that it is working for so each CA will have (could have, it is not a mandatory service) its dedicated OCSP server. OCSP request will go to the corresponding OCSP server based on the url from certificate being validated.
4. I don't know what that url is. But there is a OCSP server running at IP 23.51.123.27 according to the dump.
5. Because that is the way OCSP works :). There are only public information in the request so nothing that would require encryption. Response is signed by OCSP server issued by the same CA that issued validated certificate. Client can easily validate that the response was not tampered with (signature chech) and that it was issued by valid OCSP responder - again nothing to encrypt. Read [RFC 6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) for more information.
6. Yes, it is enough information. Certificate is identified by serial number and issuer. OCSP responder provides service for the CA that issued its certificate so OCSP server can validate that the request is valid (same issuer). OCSP server can (but is is only an extension to OCSP protocol and not widely used AFAIK) send back thumbprint of the validated certificate. It is a confirmation that OCSP server knows about the certificate.